# Increasing isolation in power splitter

Tags: rf, integrated-circuit, isolation

I want to use [This module\minicircuit Power splitter](https://ww2.minicircuits.com/pdfs/ZN2PD-9G.pdf). I am working on the 2.4GHz to 6GHz band. The isolation parameter on the stated for these frequencies in the "Typical Performance Data" table is in the range of ~20dB. Is there a way to increase the isolation to 70dB? Any other solution will be most welcome.

Comment: *Is there a way to increase the isolation to 30dB?* Sure, only use part of the frequency band. If you have attenuators/amplifiers in the signal path before the input, move them to the outputs (obviously you would need double the modules). So instead of attenuate => split you do split => attenuate.

Comment: Thanks @Bimpelrekkie. Can you, kindly,  refer me to such attenuators? I am new to this and not sure I am looking at the correct thing. If I put two of [these](https://www.pasternack.com/images/ProductPDF/PE7334-50.pdf), one on each lane, would it suffice? (note my edit from 30dB to 70 dB). Am I correct to simply sum the attenuation?

Comment: Yes, that is an attenuator, it says so in the description ;-) There are also smaller ones (the size of a connector) with a lower power rating. If you place attenuators in series, you add the attenuations. But if you first **split** the signal and attenuate each signal separately, the attenuation is **per signal**. Don't overthink this as it is not that hard! When in doubt, just measure it!